# How to encode the length of the string at the front of the string

Tags: c, protocols

Imaging I want to design a protocol, so I want to send a packet from the client side to the server side, I need to encode my data.

I have a string, I want to add the length of the string at the front of the string, for example:

```
string: "my"
which length is 2
So what I expect is to create a char[] in c and store | 2 | my | in the buffer
```

In this way, after the server receives the packet, it will know how many bytes need to be read for this request. (by using C programming)

I tried to do it but I don't know how to control the empty between the length and the string, I can create a buffer which size is 10, and use sprintf() to convert the length of the string and add it into the buffer.

Comment: "I tried to do it" --> post the code of that try.

Comment: There is always the [Better String library](https://github.com/msteinert/bstring/blob/master/doc/introduction.md) approach... (and you don't have to reinvent the wheel...)

Comment: This is very much an XY problem. Client-server protocol should transmit data length as part of its design. That said, you could always just UTF-8 encode the length of any string as the first character...

Comment: One poor way to do it is to encode the length in ASCII at the front the string - the down side is you’ll need variable `char` elements to store the length if you ever want to send anything longer than 9 chars. A better way to encode the strings length, since you are designing your own protocol, is to allocate a fixed number of bytes at the beginning, say 8 bytes, and cast &char[0] as a pointer to an `uint64_t`  Basically, use char[0~7] to store an 8byte unsigned long. Align the address w.r.t. 8byte boundary for (slightly) better performance.

Comment: You know if you think in terms of messages,you'll wind up inventing something like json  over http.  So really you just want a mime header called "Content-Length" and then your message and its properties is just a json string.

Comment: The right solution depends on the protocol. Are you going to send only plain strings or do you have a concept of a data package (e.g. how is resynchronization done in case of transmission failure)? In some cases, a string length would be implicitly given by the data package length. A protocol may also be required to be in readable text so that a human can read/write messages via a text terminal (this is probably becoming less and less common, though).

Comment: Is the `|` a kind of delimiter that shall be part of the resulting string?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you are looking for something like this: https://ideone.com/5zvTaH

Comment: @Hiiiii,  "I want to add the length of the string at the front of the string" --> Please explain why you want this.  That reason drives how it should be done.  Without that reason the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

One poor way to do it is to encode the length in ASCII at the front the string - the down side is you’ll need variable char elements to store the length if you ever want to send anything longer than 9 chars.

A better way to encode the strings length, since you are designing your own protocol, is to allocate a fixed number of bytes at the beginning, say 8 bytes, and cast &char[0] as a pointer to an uint64_t Basically, use array[0~7] to store an 8byte unsigned long. Align the address w.r.t. 8byte boundary for (slightly) better performance.

If the sender and receiver machine have different endianness, you’ll also have to include a multi-byte long “magic number” at the head of the char array. This is necessary for both sides to correctly recover the string length from the multi-byte-long length field.

Answer (score 0):

There are two standards used in C:

1. str*: `char *` which is terminated with a '\0'.
2. mem*, read/write: `void *` plus a length `size_t`.  It's the same idea for `readv()` and `writev()` but here the two variables is bundled into an array of `struct iovec`.  Note that `sizeof(size_t)` may differ between sender and render.

If you use anything else it's automatically a learning curve for whoever needs to read or interact with your code.  I wouldn't do that trade-off, but you do you.

You can, of course, encode the length into the `char *` but now you have to think about how you encode it (big vs little endian), fixed vs variable size.

You might be interested in [SDS](https://github.com/antirez/sds) which hides the length.  This way only have to reimplement the functions that change the length of the string instead of all string functions.  Use an existing library.